# getElementById in Geoext combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, geoext

How to change this code to get the ID of value extends the value from combobox?

I'm using GeoExt 1.1 and Extjs 3.4.0.  This is my code:

```
var submitButton = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Afficher sur la carte',
    handler: function () {
        var datasetId = Ext.getCmp('villeCombo').getValue();
        if (datasetId != '') {
            Ext.getCmp('tableauAttrib').store.removeAll();
            Ext.getCmp('tableauAttrib').store.proxy.protocol.params.id_promo = datasetId;
            Ext.getCmp('tableauAttrib').store.load();
        }
        else {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert("Erreur !", " alerte");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying this `to get the ID of value extends the value from combobox` ?

Comment: I want to apply getElementById to retrieve the ID of a selected field drop-down list,for use in  query